# How to build polygons with Observable and turf.js?

Tags: typescript, geojson, turfjs

I am in the process of building polygons with coordinates coming from database.
I have subscribed to an Observable to get all the coordinates (This is an Array). I push each array of coordinates in an upper Array to be able to build my polygons:

```
this.customerApi.getLocations(this.currentUser.id)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.locations = response;
      this.polygonsArray.push(this.locations);
      this.locations.forEach(element 
      => {this.polygons.push(element.geoDefinition.features['0'].geometry.coordinates);
       });
```

getLocations returns 3 Arrays:

[image]

and I push these arrays in an upper one called this.polygons:

[image]

My issue is that when I am calling `const varpolygon = turf.polygon(this.polygons);`

I am getting the following error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise): Error: Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions.
Error: Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions.
```

I think my array structure is fine as Polygons is an Array of Arrays of coordinates Arrays. Type is number[][][] like turf.polygon.

The structure of my **validated** GEOJSON is:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              5.379856000000018,
              43.252967
            ],
            [
              5.422988000000032,
              43.249466
            ],
            [
              5.425048000000061,
              43.245153
            ],
            [
              5.383804000000055,
              43.239838
            ],
            [
              5.399856,
              43.212967
            ],
            [
              5.379856000000018,
              43.252967
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              5.390139999999974,
              43.279295
            ],
            [
              5.393068999999969,
              43.279249
            ],
            [
              5.391814000000068,
              43.278421
            ],
            [
              5.390709000000015,
              43.278749
            ],
            [
              5.390899999999988,
              43.2785
            ],
            [
              5.390139999999974,
              43.279295
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -0.6070509999999558,
              44.840753
            ],
            [
              -0.5437080000000378,
              44.832962
            ],
            [
              -0.5222499999999854,
              44.820544
            ],
            [
              -0.5663670000000138,
              44.808853
            ],
            [
              -0.5863669999999956,
              44.788853
            ],
            [
              -0.6070509999999558,
              44.840753
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Could someone tell me what I did wrong if this is the case and help me?

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.polygons is an array of polygons and hence its not a single polygon

```
for(var i;i<this.polygons.length;i++){
    polygon = turf.polygon(this.polygons[i]);
}
```

In this way you can create seperate turf polygons for each different polygons.

Or if you want to create a single turf polygon what you need to do is create a turf multipolygon

```
var turfpolygon = turf.multiPolygon(this.polygons);
```

Comment: I hard coded this: `turf.multiPolygon(
        [
          [5.39014, 43.279295],
          [5.390709, 43.278749],
          [5.3909, 43.2785],
          [5.39014, 43.279295]
        ],
            [
              [5.379856, 43.252967],
              [5.422988, 43.249466],
              [5.425048, 43.245153],
             [5.379856, 43.252967]
            ]
          );` What is wrong with that ? My goal is to use pointsWithinPolygon on several polygons on the map (drawn dynamically). Looping on the Polygons is time consuming isn't it?

Comment: Hi @C.Harivignesh, I meant CPU time consuming.

Comment: I was facing an Array declaration. Too many []. I had to add one level of [].

Comment: when using turf.multipolygons the polygons should be stored in array of array such that the array passed to the turf.multipolygons should contain array with single element with will contain the polygon. A bit confusing isn't it ? So here the correct way to do it : turf.multiPolygon( [[ [5.39014, 43.279295], [5.390709, 43.278749], [5.3909, 43.2785], [5.39014, 43.279295] ], [ [5.379856, 43.252967], [5.422988, 43.249466], [5.425048, 43.245153], [5.379856, 43.252967] ] ]);